# How to list values from a select vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

how to list select values? 
[example below.](https://jsfiddle.net/y2c4pcgn/)

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

your div app was closing, in the middle of the html, you should change that to enclose all your app. Add v-model to your select multiple and you are good to show selected values.

```
<select multiple v-model="selected">
```

your data

```
  data() {
    return {
      selected: []
    }
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gmy2hmhp/

Comment: and if I want to list without selecting element within the select?

Comment: what do you mean by list without selecting?

Comment: pick up the existing elements within the select.